# Improving ASP.Net login code and checking if user is logged in

Tags: asp.net

There are two things I want to accomplish with my ASP.net code which I am struggling to right now because I am a beginner:

1) My code in **Login.aspx** is currently susceptible to SQL injection, how can I minimise my risk of SQL injection?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Web.Configuration;

public partial class login : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
        string username = Login_Box.UserName;
        string pwd = Login_Box.Password;

        string strConn;
        strConn = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["team13ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
        Conn.Open();

        string sqlUserName;
        sqlUserName = "SELECT id,pass FROM ts_dept ";
        sqlUserName += " WHERE (id ='" + username + "')";
        sqlUserName += " AND (pass ='" + pwd + "')";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sqlUserName, Conn);

        string CurrentName;
        CurrentName = (string)com.ExecuteScalar();

        if (CurrentName != null)
        {
            Session["UserAuthentication"] = username;
            Session.Timeout = 1;
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            Session["UserAuthentication"] = "";
        }
    }
}
```

2) **Default.aspx** is the home page of my website. It cannot be accessed if the user has not logged in, how do I check for Session["Authentication"] here (if null then the user is redirected to **Login.aspx**. Here is my code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Team13
{
    public partial class default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by putting server validation on the text boxes. Perhaps a max length would help? Also prevent apostrophes from being used.

Try something like this for part two, perhaps test for empty string as well:

```
If (Session("UserAuthentication") Is Nothing) 
{
    Response.Redirect("Login.aspx")
}
```

### Update

Forms authentication deals with both of the issues you have and is built in. If you need to, you can customise it to suit your needs. A good tutorial can be found at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/408306/Understanding-and-Implementing-ASP-NET-Custom-Form

Alternatively, you could change your SQL command to bring back the password for the username provided and do a string comparison after you have got your data back.

```
"SELECT pass FROM ts_dept WHERE (id ='" + username + "')";
```

Comment: Because I've directly placed the password on my sql call, I am exposed to SQL injection. If someone types for password 1') OR ('1'='1 then someone would get in.

Comment: @methuselah Hence my suggestion for preventing apostrophes. Is there a reason why you are not using the built in forms authentication?

Answer (score 2):

Look at using [parameterised sql](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) to prevent the sql injection attacks.

Generally however I would recommend using the asp.net universal providers for membership as these will ensure you have a robust/secure membership functionality

See [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx) and [this](http://blogs.msmvps.com/luisabreu/blog/2012/09/24/adding-the-simplemembership-provider-to-an-asp-net-web-forms-app/) to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

The best practices for preventing sql injection are:

1. Use command parameter for passing any user values to sql for
   excecuting statement.
2. Always user sp_execute() system stored procedure for executing sql
   statements on DB
3. Always validate user input values before putting values sql
   statements.